# Мониторинг оборудования с привязкой на карте по snmp

Tags: ubuntu, grafana

Возможно ли реализовать интерактивный мониторинг состояния оборудования (snmp датчик) на карте с изменением цвета дома (например: пропало напряжение/сигнал - раскраска дома поменялась с зеленого на красный) около 100 объектов с опросом через каждые 5 мин.

Comment: да, возможно реализовать

Comment: Есть готовое решение? Или надо скрипты писать?